# I never knew she went to London

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

Someone said this sentence is incorrect. They said, "if you never knew something, you still don't know it."

> I never knew she went to London.

Actually I do not understand their logic. "I never knew" refers to the past. If I never knew something in the past, that doesn't necessarily mean I still don't know it now.

What would you think?

Comment: It seems well within the range of things a native speaker would say or write without anyone noticing that something was "wrong."

Answer (score 1):

One typically says "I never knew" a fact immediately upon learning a new fact. Since the fact is known when the statement is made (and even a moment before), I suppose that, in a technical sense, the statement is not true when it is uttered.

Dispensing with this technical point, though, all the statement says is that you didn't know the fact until you (apparently just recently) found out. In your example, if someone tells you that a woman went to London, you might say, "I never knew she went to London" to express that you are just now finding out that she did.

When used to express that a fact has just been learned, I don't see any difference between "I never knew" and "I didn't know" other than a stylistic one. The "never" version sounds perhaps more taken aback, but it can also come across as less formal and in certain cases has almost a childish quality.

Comment: In the dialect local to Bristol (UK) where I live, many people say 'I never' instead of 'I didn't'.

Comment: So, is this sentence "I never knew she went to London" correct? It seems to me that it's correct grammatically, but you advise not using it, due to some unknown reasons.

Comment: Everyone has told you that it's a perfectly natural thing to say, even though a purist may find fault with the logic.

Comment: @Stephen, it's correct. You can always replace it with "I didn't know..." I advise against using it until you get a sense for when it's appropriate. I briefly mentioned a few stylistic differences, but didn't attempt a full explanation of when it's appropriate, since that wasn't the question. It would actually be rather difficult to answer...

Comment: One thing I can tell you is that it would only make sense to say "I never knew" something if there was some chance of knowing it a reasonable while back into the past. If you meet someone for the first time, and an hour later the person tells you an interesting fact about himself, you might say "I didn't know that," but you wouldn't say "I never knew that."